# How to load the DateTimePicker with ShowCheckBox unchecked

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a DateTimePicker control with ShowCheckBox set to true.

```
DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker();
dateTimePicker1.ShowCheckBox = true;
```

When this gets executed the check box is displayed to the left of the selected date and it is checked.

Would it be possible to load the DateTimePicker with this checkbox **unchecked**, so the DateTimePicker control will be disabled when the form is loaded and users will have to check the checkbox to enable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set [DateTimePicker.Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.checked.aspx) property for that, you can use the following code:

```
DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker();
dateTimePicker1.ShowCheckBox = true;
dateTimePicker1.Checked= false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTimePicker.Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.checked.aspx) property to set checked state:

```
dateTimePicker1.Checked = false;
```